# How to update a text field without using the useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

**I have a component structured like this:**

```
export const EditProductDescription = ({ product, lang, onChange, onSubmit }: ProductDescriptionInterface) => {
  let editedProduct = { ...product };
  const handleChange = (field: string, value: string, multiLanguage: boolean) => {
    multiLanguage
      ? { ...editedProduct, description: { [field]: { [lang]: value } } }
      : { ...editedProduct, description: { [field]: value } };

    console.log(editedProduct);
  };

  return (
    <TextArea
      id="description"
      placeholder="Description"
      value={editedProduct.details.description.text[lang] || ' '}
      label="Description"
      onChange={e => handleChange('text', e.target.value, true)}
    />
  );
};
```

**My Product model ist structured like this:**

```
export class Product {
    ...
    details: {
        ...
        description: {
            ...
            text: {de?: string, en?: string}
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to update the description of the product or have the opportunity to edit it.

With my current approach, the product object is not updated as desired. Accordingly, the value in the text field is not updated either.

My handleChange method  receives the field I want to edit as a parameter. The multiLanguage parameter is also used to specify whether this should be created in multiple languages. Multilingualism is important here.

How do I have to adapt my handleChange method so that I can get the result I want without using the useState hook? Is that even possible?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're passing in `onChange` as a prop, but not calling it in `handleChange`. When the `onChange` event in the `TextArea` fires, your function just returns an object; does `TextArea` use that return value? If you don't want to use `useState` within your component to handle the value changing, then a parent component should be passing the new value into this component's props (which I assume is what the `onChange` prop is for). What you should probably be doing is bubbling the change up through each component's `onChange`, until you reach a point where you use `useState`.

Comment: In your `handleChange` function you're not assigning the modified object back to `editedProduct`.
`editedProduct = multiLanguage ? { ...editedProduct, description: { [field]: { [lang]: value } } }  : { ...editedProduct, description: { [field]: value } };`

Comment: @BillyBrown As you have already recognized, I forgot to call up the onChange method :(. In the end I solved it in such a way that I passed the onChange event on to the parent over two levels with prop drilling. I then called the onChangeHandler in the parent and dispatched my action there. Thank you for your explanation, which put me on the right path.

Comment: @Codehan25 You can add an answer to your own question and then mark it as correct, so that anybody who finds your question in the future will see the answer as well.